# How webapp2 get checkbox values, and the name is the same?

Tags: python, webapp2

How webapp2 get checkbox values from jinja2 templates, and the name is the same ? Is the data structure is Dict ? How can get it and pass it ?

html templates:

...

```
{% for tablename in tablenames %}
<input type = "checkbox" name = "tn">{{tablename}}
{% endfor %}
```

...

main.py:

```
tn = self.request.get('tn')
```

Thank you guys : )

How get the checkbox value and pass it into tn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your template should be...

```
{% for tablename in tablenames %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="tn" value="{{ tablename }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

And the code should be (I believe that `.GET` also handles `.POST` vars as well in WebApp2):

```
tn = self.request.GET['tn']
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i read the docs and solve it, thanks : )